# Json converting json array object to json object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have json with below structure. I want to remove the array and make that a object as there will be only one element in that array. What is the best way to do this. I don't want to hardcode any node other than `students` and `student` node in the code

Input JSON

```
{
  "students": {
    "a": "qw",
    "b": "er",
    "student": [
      {
        "Id": "1",
        "details": {
         
          "q": "12",
          "w": "wer",
          "e": "rty",
          "r": "yui"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Output JSON

```
{
  "students": {
    "a": "qw",
    "b": "er",
    "student": {
      "Id": "1",
      "details": {
        "q": "12",
        "w": "wer",
        "e": "rty",
        "r": "yui"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

    jObj["students"]["student"] = jObj["students"]["student"][0];

    json = jObj.ToString();
```